# Path error for loading a csv file from GitHub

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I would like to ask what is the problem to load data from Github. The first below code can return an array from the path.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
wine_path ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/master/data/p1ch4/tabular-wine/winequality-white.csv"
wineq_numpy = np.loadtxt(wine_path,  dtype = np.float32, delimiter=";", skiprows=1) 

wineq_numpye
```

However, the second below code returns the error although the same path is used.

```
col_list = next(csv.reader(open(wine_path),  delimiter=';'))
wineq_numpy.shape, col_list
```

The massage mentions

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deep-learning-with-pytorch/dlwpt-code/master/data/p1ch4/tabular-wine/winequality-white.csv'
```

What is the cause of the error? I just write the code on google-colab.
Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('path')
```